# Input [type='datetime-local'] doesn't support seconds in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Using the [datetime-local](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/datetime-local) input type on Chrome doesn't seem to work when the value is set via Javascript and the value contains seconds. Why is this happening? It seems to be a general thing. In simple terms, here's how to re-create the problem:

1. Create an `input` element with `type='datetime-local'`.
2. Set the value to any date and time using JavaScript (using `.value`) with a **non-zero seconds** (eg. `'1980-01-01T01:01:01.001'`) value.
3. Try submitting the form. It returns a validation error.

**But**, if you set the seconds to 0 (eg. `1980-01-01T01:01:00.001`), or the value is set via HTML attributes, then the validation error doesn't get thrown and the form submits fine.

See this CodePen sample: http://codepen.io/AskYous/pen/KNONVG

Comment: Perhaps you should report it as a bug to [*Google*](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a bug in Chrome. I found a solution. Use the `.setAttribute()` function:

`datetimeInput.setAttribute('value', '1980-01-01T01:01:01.001');`

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected behavior defined by the HTML standard.

The default `step` value for `type=datetime-local` is 1 minute.  The default step-base is Unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00.  So `1980-01-01T01:01:01.001` causes a step-mismatch validation error.

If `min` attribute or `value` attribute is specified, it would be the step-base.